# enable php-mssql on plesk 11 linux server(Media Temple)

Tags: linux, sql-server-2005, plesk, mediatemple, dedicated-server

I need to connect to both mssql and MySQL using php. so I tried to enable extension php-mssql using yum install my-mssql, when I have PHP 5 support, it says php-api missing. And get suggested to using php5.3 instead, after I switch, it get error php54-common is conflicted with php-common.

Comment: Which OS is on your server? CentOS 6?